# Why does `grails war` create a different WAR every time?

Tags: grails, md5, war

Why does `grails war` generate a different WAR file every time? In the command line, I observe the following behavior.

```
$ grails test war
| Done creating WAR target/foo-2.5.3.war
MacBook-Air:foo mba$ md5 target/foo-2.5.3.war 
MD5 (target/foo-2.5.3.war) = af45e22b24d158a72c9a0db67cd31417

$ grails test war
| Done creating WAR target/foo-2.5.3.war
MacBook-Air:foo mba$ md5 target/foo-2.5.3.war 
MD5 (target/foo-2.5.3.war) = 157635f7d152cb56bc3b5bd731a8fb6e
```

Without changing a thing, all I did was run the same `grails test war` command twice in a row. The WAR file generated from the second run has a different MD5 checksum than the first. Can anyone help me understand why? For what it's worth I'm running Grails 2.5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Grails generates a war it inserts or updates timestamps in several places with a default application (`grails create-app foo` -> `grails war`).

There are timestamps in:

- `application.properties`
- `views.properties`
- `manifest.properties`

Additionally, the ordering of strings in some of these properties files is not guaranteed, so some lines appear in different order on subsequent runs.

Here's the full diff I got:

```
diff -ru tmp1/ tmp2/
diff -ru tmp1/WEB-INF/classes/application.properties tmp2/WEB-INF/classes/application.properties
--- tmp1/WEB-INF/classes/application.properties 2016-05-23 16:36:44.000000000 -0400
+++ tmp2/WEB-INF/classes/application.properties 2016-05-23 16:37:24.000000000 -0400
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-#Mon, 23 May 2016 16:36:43 -0400
+#Mon, 23 May 2016 16:37:24 -0400
 #Grails Metadata file
 #Mon May 23 16:35:56 EDT 2016
 app.grails.version=2.5.1
diff -ru tmp1/WEB-INF/classes/gsp/views.properties tmp2/WEB-INF/classes/gsp/views.properties
--- tmp1/WEB-INF/classes/gsp/views.properties   2016-05-23 16:36:42.000000000 -0400
+++ tmp2/WEB-INF/classes/gsp/views.properties   2016-05-23 16:37:22.000000000 -0400
@@ -1,8 +1,8 @@
 #Precompiled views for databaseMigration
-#Mon May 23 16:36:42 EDT 2016
+#Mon May 23 16:37:21 EDT 2016
 /WEB-INF/plugins/database-migration-1.4.0/grails-app/views/dbdoc/_overview-summary.gsp=gsp_databaseMigration_dbdoc_overview_summary_gsp
-/WEB-INF/plugins/database-migration-1.4.0/grails-app/views/dbdoc/_stylesheet.gsp=gsp_databaseMigration_dbdoc_stylesheet_gsp
 /WEB-INF/plugins/database-migration-1.4.0/grails-app/views/dbdoc/_index.gsp=gsp_databaseMigration_dbdoc_index_gsp
+/WEB-INF/plugins/database-migration-1.4.0/grails-app/views/dbdoc/_stylesheet.gsp=gsp_databaseMigration_dbdoc_stylesheet_gsp
 /WEB-INF/grails-app/views/index.gsp=gsp_5index_gsp
 /WEB-INF/plugins/database-migration-1.4.0/grails-app/views/dbdoc/_globalnav.gsp=gsp_databaseMigration_dbdoc_globalnav_gsp
 /WEB-INF/grails-app/views/layouts/main.gsp=gsp_5_layoutsmain_gsp
diff -ru tmp1/assets/manifest.properties tmp2/assets/manifest.properties
--- tmp1/assets/manifest.properties 2016-05-23 16:36:54.000000000 -0400
+++ tmp2/assets/manifest.properties 2016-05-23 16:37:26.000000000 -0400
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
 #
-#Mon May 23 16:36:53 EDT 2016
+#Mon May 23 16:37:25 EDT 2016
 apple-touch-icon-retina.png=apple-touch-icon-retina-21d524e96ee946f16c9b8fb4ea0c3f6e.png
 skin/information.png=skin/information-3750c701d2ec35a45d289b9b9c1a0667.png
 skin/database_add.png=skin/database_add-82a75143b4660a3f02f9c058f0a3ae93.png
@@ -20,9 +20,9 @@
 errors.css=errors-81f3e38a6e878acd57e3d51912c37b04.css
 main.css=main-46ae5880f56b5942fc138e25d2f87c47.css
 jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.map=jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min-ffbeb16578d8cdf58104889baacbbef2.map
-favicon.ico=favicon-9ef27019cc7a636e29ecc851528f716e.ico
 skin/database_save.png=skin/database_save-8303213a3c95654e14d5afd4e72ed4c2.png
-skin/sorted_desc.gif=skin/sorted_desc-b85986b88116c4b0ef7571a1c4f3cfa3.gif
+favicon.ico=favicon-9ef27019cc7a636e29ecc851528f716e.ico
 grails_logo.png=grails_logo-eabe4af98753b0163266d7e68bbd32e3.png
+skin/sorted_desc.gif=skin/sorted_desc-b85986b88116c4b0ef7571a1c4f3cfa3.gif
 jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js=jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min-ac124bf54878ec7f20b578d3e627d6a8.js
 skin/house.png=skin/house-99bea32e1990e011e870f6c562e87a6a.png
```